# Django Restframework update manytomany via through table

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have following models and one another ClientWarehouse. For some reasons i have to create ManyToManyField Relation via a through table named RouteInfo

```
class Route(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    warehouse = models.ManyToManyField(ClientWarehouse,
                                       verbose_name='Warehouse Location',
                                       through='RouteInfo',
                                       blank=True, null=True)

class RouteInfo(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(ClientWarehouse)
```

i have following serializer class writtern

```
class RouteInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RouteInfo


class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    warehouse = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Route
```

And Following Viewset

```
class RouteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Route

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Route.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Route.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def create(self, request, format=None):
        r = RouteSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if r.is_valid():
            r.save()
            return Response(r.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(r.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However on going through the documentation of DRF i found that it does not support write operations on a ManytoManyField via through table.

Currently when i try to save the route via the api call, it does not save the clientwarehouse, ie the RouteInfo table is not created, but the Route object is created with no clientwarehouse in it.

Is there any way i can update the through table ie RouteInfo while creating a route in Route table.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively i found that i can acomplish the same by first saving the Route Instance and the using the Route.id and warehouse to save into RouteInfo model.

Hence this turned into two step process. First saving the original model and then saving the through model.